# Xcode: SRCROOT not working even though paths seem to exist

Tags: xcode, path, include-path

I am receiving "file not found" errors when compiling in Xcode. My paths are specified relative to $SRCROOT and seem to be correctly identified. What's the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that my $SRCROOT path included spaces. All you need to do is quote SRCROOT like this: "$SRCROOT" and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was another. Try to check your path to headers. For example, I had a path in Headers Search Paths:

**"$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/KIF"**

But my KIF folder was actually here:

**"$(SRCROOT)/../Frameworks/KIF"**

or by other words, one level up to my source root. That is why, when I changed SRCROOT to hardcoded path, my headers were found.