# How can I escape the spaces in $SRCROOT in my run script in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, path, escaping, run-script

I have a run script that gets the value of the current project's path via $SRCROOT. I pass this path as a parameter to an app in the script. The problem is that if my project name has a space, $SRCROOT doesn't evaluate to the full, correct path. It truncates after the first space.

Is it possible to escape $SRCROOT within this run script build phase in Xcode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060537/985027) that you just need to wrap it in quotes: `"$SRCROOT"`